# water fountain with a pipette

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

if you get some hot water in a pipette an put the pick of it on the top the water will jump out f pipette and make a fountain.I wondered if any one could tell me what is the reason?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you half fill the pipette with hot water. So at that point it's filled half with hot water in the lower part, half filled with air *at room temperature* in the upper part. Then you block the top end of the pipette with the tip of your finger and turn the pipette upside down, so the hot water starts flowing down to the blocked side.

However, the presence of hot water now causes the colder air to warm up quickly and expand accordingly. This causes some (mild) pressure to build inside the pipette and water starts being expelled by this pressure. This expelled water is the jet you see leaving the pipette.

The 'trick' works because gases (like air) expand very considerably on heating, roughly in accordance with the [Ideal Gas Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law). Also, the shape of the pipette helps because the hot water in the top part (after having turned the pipette upside down) takes time to flow to the lower part. This means there's usually enough water in the top part be be expelled by the heating, expanding air.

Comment: so.why the water expelled when we turn the pipette?if there is pressure it doesn't make difference if we turn it or not.

Comment: The pressure is caused by the air warming up and expanding. The air heats up when the hot water runs past it when you turn the pipette upside down and the water starts running downwards.

Comment: Pressure would also build (but more slowly) if you didn't turn the pipette upside down but then you wouldn't get the effect of a vertical fountain (which is what makes this trick attractive).

Comment: what about the effect of difference of density and capillarity between water and glass?

Comment: These play no role here whatsoever, I believe. It's purely due to using hot water, causing the colder air to heat up and expand. The resulting pressure increase causes the fountain effect. The hotter the water the stronger the effect will be.

Comment: I have experimented this theory ( the pressure of hot water) how I can calculate the max height that water can rich.

Comment: ? difference of pressure is 9.6 pa

Comment: The pressure increase can be estimated using the Ideal Gas law. But then it gets really complicated because you need to set up an equation of motion for that water flowing through a tube with a constricted end. In my opinion that isn't worth doing.

Comment: don't you think it can be solved by the Bernoulli's principal?A1*V1 = A2*V2.the only thing will be the first velocity. I don't what is the next.

Comment: That would work if you knew V1. But that would have to calculated first. There pressure loss when the water flows through the pipette's tube. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_flow.

Comment: what if we assume that the experiment is is in the ideal condition?